# Exported EXR looks very different than exported PNG. Using Color Management

Tags: rendering, color, color-management, octane-render-engine

I am using Octane in Blender and I've set my Color Management settings as follows:

[image: Settings]

For this scene I felt that a RAW view transform with look set to "None" gave me a better result because it exaggerates the dispersion effect I want.

Anyway, I rendered the scene and saved an EXR and a PNG.

For some reason the EXR looks incredibly washed out. Like some kind of view transform has been applied.

Images for reference:

PNG:
[image: PNG]

EXR:
[image: EXR]

Is there a way to disable this? Can someone possibly explain to me what's going on?

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: It does. Wow that was simple. Thank you!